# Fetch all available documents From S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services

How do we fetch all available files from S3 bucket with all documents details like there owner added date etc.

Answer (score 2):

To copy all files from a S3 bucket to your current directory you can do:

`aws s3 cp --recursive s3://my-bucket .`

To get their metadata you should do (up to 1000 objects):

`aws s3api list-objects --bucket s3://my-bucket`

Comment: @ManojPatel if you want to interact with the S3 service from PHP then you should probably use the AWS SDK for PHP (https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/) rather than execing the awscli.